# mtime.sec is not present

Tags: java, scp

I am facing a tricky situation here. I have a java based application that tries to scp remote machines to copy certain files. While performing those tasks , I am finding the below error message from the application side.

```
scp protocol error mtime.sec not present
```

But when I manually try to scp from the server to endpoint machine, I am able to do it without issues.

The command I am using for manual testing is  `scp localfile user@hostname:/tmp/`

I am not sure of the error message `mtime.sec is not present` . Does anyone can throw some lights here. I couldn't find useful info from web, Any experts thoughts would help a lot.

As SCP is working normally using manual process, I am not sure there is something wrong with SCP.

Comment: I used `-vvvv` to find out. The real problem was `Too many logins`. The server accepted only two logins at a time.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I've got the same issue. It worked for me if I scp to ubuntu 12.04. When I did that to ubuntu 14.04, it failed with same message.

I wrote the scp code based on this example http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/ScpTo.java.html. I guess you too.

If I remove the whitespace after the "T" in the following line, it'll work.  Change:

```
command="T "+(_lfile...
```

to

```
command="T"+(_lfile...
```

Either do that or set ptimestamp = false

Comment: Yes , I agree... I too had to update the command and it worked , I missed to update the question here.. thanks for your input

Comment: Yep, exactly same issue here with that example... Thank you for the solution! I'll try to notify the authors of that example somehow.

Comment: how do i `set ptimestamp = false`, please?  Tks in advance.

Comment: inside file [ScpTo.java](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/ScpTo.java.html), around line 40, you will see how to use that flag

Answer (score 9):

Like ZZapper above writes.

I ran into the same issue as above, trying to use scp to connect to a remote site and it also told me
 "protocol error: mtime.sec not delimited "

Running `scp with -vvvv` it turned out on the 'server side' they disallowed me to use scp and told me to use sftp instead.

Answer (score 3):

I learned my issue derived from the fact that our stftp server solely allows sftp connections. scp is not allowed.

```
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0
Sink: This service allows sftp connections only.
protocol error: mtime.sec not present
```

Answer (score 2):

```
protocol error: mtime.sec not delimited
```

I Googled this and learnt that this is a convoluted error message. We recently disabled our root login by making it 'nologin'. I forgot to update my scp script which was still trying to login as root. When I updated it use the new login all was fine. (sorry nothing to do with Java)